# Put a stake through [dracula]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Sorry if I'm doing this wrong - my first burnination request, so I'm not really sure of the procedure. I suspect I was supposed to come up with a brilliant pun on the word Dracula and burning, but there are too many good options :)

Anyway, at the time of writing the [dracula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dracula) has [5 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dracula), three of which are common misspellings of the 'darcula' colour scheme, at least two of which should probably be closed anyway, and two referring to a JS library called [Graph Dracula](https://www.graphdracula.net/) but maybe that should have a 'graph-dracula' tag?

To answer the questions in [When to burninate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It's sort-of ambiguous in that there is a library with that name, and a commonly-used and commonly-misspelled colour scheme with a very similar name - or, really, more than a common-misspelling, lots of people actually think the colour scheme is called 'Dracula', because they can't read good. (It has come to my attention that in fact, I am the one who can't read good, but I'll leave this here as evidence of my stupidity, and another good reason why we should avoid snark in our posts :P)

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

The library probably is; the colour scheme probably isn't.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Probably, but for the colour scheme it would be better if it's spelled correctly (obviously!) and for the library graph-dracula might be more meaningful.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Nope.

Comment: Several of the five questions were asking about a color theme [whose name really is Dracula](https://draculatheme.com/sublime/) for all I can tell. The color theme is hardly a good thing to have a tag for so I removed the tag from those. The two remaining questions are about the Angular graph library you mention.

Comment: Wait. Now I'm so confused! There are colour schemes called both _Dracula_ and _Darcula_? The built-in one in IntelliJ is Darcula, but it looks like you can also get a third party one called Dracula. What's wrong with the world? :D

Comment: I wonder if someone can add some useful description to the tag to say that it's for the JS library? I don't know that world well enough to feel confident doing it without revealing my ignorance.

Comment: Why no punny title? I mean, this one is just... Stake, crucifix, silver bullet, garlic... Take your pick. Just pick something, please!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett - I know! But I couldn't find something that actually made sense, where I wouldn't need to explain it with a (by the way this is a burninate request). In my defence it's still early here, please feel free to edit the title to make it awesome :)

Comment: Suck the questions out of [dracula]?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave Done. All: Feel free to improve.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Improved, I hope! I thought of trying a "help vampire"-related pun, but it might fall foul of the "Be Nice" policy...

Comment: The Dracula tag is at stake. Puns aside, there's so few questions here that we don't need to roll out a full, formal burnination (torches and pitchforks?). Someone's already started cleaning the tag. The last two could be re-tagged to some graph-dracula tag, if we need one. Otherwise, if we don't (I don't know the topic so I can't tell), someone can just edit the tag out.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really didn't like the previous title so I changed it to something that is hopefully better. Feel free te revert, comment or improve it.

Comment: Does the graph dracula pun even work in English? (German "Graf", which sounds equal to graph, is a title of nobility)

Comment: Oh! It doesn't work at all, but I'm glad to understand that now :) I haven't even attended my stand up yet, and have already learned something today!